# Sketching a set in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Given the set $2 < |z-1| < 5$, how could you sketch this set in the complex plane? I understand how to do it if it were just $|z-1| < 5$, but I'm stuck on how to do it with two inequalities. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Think of the points in the complex plane whose distance to $1$ is greater than $2$ but less than $5$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2 < |z-1| < 5 \iff 2 < |z-1|, \text {and  } |z-1| < 5$$

As you know $ |z-1| < 5$ is the set of points inside the circle of radius $5$ and centered at $z=1.$

On the other hand, the set $ 2 < |z-1| $ is the set of points outside the circle of radius $2$ and centered at $z=1.$

Thus  $$ 2 < |z-1| < 5 $$ is  the  region between the two circles.

Comment: Oh okay that makes so much sense, thank you!